# primeng editor : Add custom format to primeng editor

Tags: javascript, primeng, rich-text-editor, quill

I have integrated the editor from primeng like so.

```
<p-editor [(ngModel)]="value" [style]="{'height':'100px'}">
    <p-header>
       <span class="ql-formats">
        <button class="ql-bold" aria-label="Bold"></button>
        <button class="ql-italic" aria-label="Italic"></button>
       </span>
    </p-header>
</p-editor>
```

I want to add a custom format for Bold like so

```
let Inline = Quill.import('blots/inline');
class BoldBlot extends Inline { }
      BoldBlot["blotName"] = 'bold';
      BoldBlot["tagName"] = 'B';
      Quill.register(BoldBlot);
```

On click of bold button I want the custom tag "B" to be added instead of the default strong.

I have tried to invoke $event.editor.format('bold', true); but this dosen't work. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using JSF? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging